# How to bind the IsEnabled Property of a WPF ListBoxItem to a Property of its Source Item?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, listboxitem

I have a ListBox with an `ObservableCollection` as `ItemSource`:

```cs
public partial class HomePage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<DaemonFile> Files { get; private set; }
    private readonly MainWindow MainWindow;

    public HomePage(MainWindow MainWindow)
    {
        Files = new ObservableCollection<DaemonFile>();

        this.MainWindow = MainWindow;

        InitializeComponent();

        ListOfFiles.ItemsSource = Files;
    }
    ...
}
```

I have the following properties in my `DaemonFile`:

```
public class DaemonFile : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public enum ProcessStates : int
    {
        CREATED = 0,
        CONVERTED = 1,
        UPLOADING = 2,
        FINISHED = 3
    }
    private ProcessStates ProcessStateValue = ProcessStates.CREATED;
    public ProcessStates ProcessState 
    { 
        get { return this.ProcessStateValue; } 
        set 
        {
           if (value != this.ProcessStateValue)
           {
               this.ProcessStateValue = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged();
           }
        } 
     }
    ...
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            mainWindow.WriteLine("Property " + propertyName + " Changed!");
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        } else
        {
            mainWindow.WriteLine("Cant fire event!");
        }
    }
}
```

The `ProcessState` gets updated asynchronously after the conversion of the file has finished.
I figured I need to bind this property and put it into a setter for `IsEnabled`.

```xml
        <Style x:Key="Item" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter 
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ProcessState}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger> 
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

How can I achieve that whenever a `DaemonFile` changes its `ProcessState` to 1 or higher the corresponding ListBoxItem switches to enabled?

- I don't want a user to be able to upload a file before it has finished converting

I could also add an `isEnabled` property to my `DaemonFile` to simplify things a little. That doesn't solve my binding problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need that ControlTemplate.

A simple DataTrigger should work:

```
<Style x:Key="ItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ProcessState}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Trigers>
</Style>
```

Just in case:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListOfFiles"
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemStyle}" ...>
```

Comment: If I do that, it is getting disabled but not enabled. So I cant interact with it at all. I also tried to do another trigger for enabling it but that doesn´t seem to work. Thx for the quick answer btw.

Comment: It will get enabled if you do not set IsEnabled anywhere else. And of course do not use the ControlTemplate from your question.

Comment: Do I need to fire a property change event on Update on Process state?

Comment: Okay. I have implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged into the DaemonFile Class. When Setting the Process State I Invoke PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Name));

Comment: It is updating the state but the ui does not react to the change. When I change the value of the CREATED state to something other than 0 it is getting enabled.

Comment: `new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Name)` is apparently wrong. It should be `new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ProcessState))`. And you have set the property before firing the event. Consider a regular property implementation where the PropertyChanged event is fired in the property setter, after setting the backing field - as a replacement for the SetProcessState method.

Comment: I added the NotifyPropertyChanged Method - working alongside this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=net-5.0

Comment: Come on, you are not calling the NotifyPropertyChanged method from the ProcessState setter... It must be a property with backing field, where the setter fires the change notification, like CustomerName in the example.

Comment: Yeah I just fixed that. It is working now. Thanks so much!